# Run test cases online without depending on local IDE

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Is there anyway where i can use my github code to run test cases online instantly without depending on local IDE ?

Comment: github will only hold your code, not execute it.  I think you would need to do something like get yourself an AWS EC2 instance, put your code there, and set up something like a web server that you can use to invoke it...

Comment: Is there anything something like AWS EC2 instance which i get for free ?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/03/aws-codepipeline-adds-support-for-unit-testing/

Comment: You get an EC2 instance (small VM) for free for the first year, when you first sign up with them.  I like JoeHZ's reference - I did not know about it :-p (though I am not sure you will get that one for free...)